# What is the explanation of splitting an Out-Of-Time Sample into train and test?

Tags: train-test-split, credit-scoring

I'm working with a dataset to train a credit risk model. The dataset already has flags for how it should be split so results can be reproduced, it has a column with two values `DEV`, for development, and `OOT` for out-of-time. But then again I have another column that determines if the register will be used for train or test. What I find confusing is that for the `OOT` sample I have both `train` and `test` rows. Shouldn't the `OOT` rows only be used for validation? Or is it a common practice to split the `OOT` sample into train and test and include the `train` part to train the model?